# Unlimited engine option does not work

Tags: motor

I  work in a school and all my Lego NXT bricks have the same problem. Unlimited choice in the activation time engine does not work. The other functions (rotation, and second degree) are going well. So I can use my probes and so I am very limited in the tasks to be performed.

I've done these actions, but without success:

- Reset On my brick
- Update Bricks
- Update The program to version 1.31
- Contact My representative

Comment: EV3 software?  or NXT?

Comment: Are you able to summarise your program or post a picture of it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to ensure that your program has a way to stay alive (wait block, wait for sensor, etc...), otherwise as soon as the program ends all motors are stopped.

Comment: Looks like a comment to me.